# Using matlab mex files with R

Tags: r, matlab

I would want to use a certain function written in c for use with matlab, with the mex system.
Any ideas/experience about how to port this to R?

Since comments say this is to vague, some detail. There is a certain well-written matlab function I need for use with R (All the rest of my code are in R). This function have an empty
m-file, only documentation. All the work is in the corresponding .c-file, but this is c-code written specifically for use with matlab, so contains a lot of calls to mx-functions, which I understand are hooks into the inner life of matlab.

The suggestion to communicate via data files will not work, I need this function within an iterative algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This pdf file](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s243/calling.pdf) might give you some tips. I don't have any experience with using C with R, but it seems possible.

One method not mentioned in the file, which I like to use sometimes, is to simply use your MATLAB/R program to write out a text file of numbers to be input into your C program (e.g. `c_data.dat`), and then to use a system command to call a standalone C program which processes the data file, before spewing out some output numbers (e.g. `c_output.dat`). Then get your MATLAB/R program to read in the data from the file.

In MATLAB, this might look like this:

```
%# custom function to write to file
function_write_data( my_data_matrix, 'c_data.dat'); 

%# call the c program
system('./c_program c_data.dat c_output.dat');

%# read the results
my_results_matrix = function_read_data('c_output.dat');
```

(I'm not confident about the R syntax - you'll have to work that out for yourself!)

The advantage of this in your scenario is that you could use exactly the same C program for both R and MATLAB. You have to write the read/write functions though, and for some scenarios the read/write overheads could be prohibitive (i.e not give any noticeable increase in speed)..